# Working with fragment getting error while compiling the code

Tags: android

I am working with fragment, but getting this error while compiling the code:

`c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe` finished with non-zero exit

```
value  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/aquery.jar')
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile fileTree(include: 'Parse-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile ('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

Comment: Build -> Clean Project  and then go to Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection between your fragments and above errors. Please check your build.gradle (app level) file. Your are adding multiple dependencies for libraries (.jar) in your build.gradle file.

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

This is sufficient for adding all libraries in libs folder. **Because * (star) indicates all JAR files in libs folder.**

Comment: Sir , please can you give modified dependencies.